# java comparator, comparing strings by number of words

Tags: java, comparator

I need some help with java comparator.  I need to compare strings by the number of words they contain.

For example, "hello" comes before "I see" which comes before "I see you".

Anyone got any ideas how I would do this? Thank you in advance for any help you could give.

Comment: Here is the [documentation for Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class WordCountComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        if (str1 == str2 || (str1 == null && str2 == null)) {
            return 0;
        } else if (str1 == null) {
            return -1;
        } else if (str2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        int len1 = new StringTokenizer(str1, " \t\r\n").countTokens();
        int len2 = new StringTokenizer(str2, " \t\r\n").countTokens();
        return len1 < len2 ? -1 : len1 == len2 ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using regular expressions is tricky and may be not a robust solution, prefer `BreakIterator`.

Comment: @David Olivan Ubetio: This solution does not use regular expressions.

Comment: Agreed that regular expressions are not robust, and they're expensive. Edited answer to avoid using them in `String.split()` and use `StringTokenizer.countTokens()` in favor.

Answer (score 1):

Write a comparator for a String type. In the compareTo method, simply call string.split(" ") to break it down to 'words' (if that's sufficient), then return the comparison between those two integers.

Answer (score 1):

`string.split(" ")` will return an array, where each element is a word. So comparing the number of elements in the array would give you a rough implementation of this. Obviously you may need to handle line-breaks, tabs etc., so keep that in mind.

[Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) also has some useful methods to do this.

Comment: Better to use `BreakIterator` to separate words.

Comment: Wow, how have I never seen that class. I agree, +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

      public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if(o1==null && o2 ==null)
        return 0;
        String[] bo1 = o1.split("\\s");
        String[] bo2 = o2.split("\\s");
        return bo1.length >= bo2.length ? bo1.length > bo2.length ? 1 : 0 : -1;
      }
}
```